# Question about splitting field

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $e$ primitive root of $x^{13}-1$ and v be vector in splitting field $Z_p(e)$.
Can we let $(a_{11}*e^{11}+a_{10}*e^{10}+...+a_1*e+a_0)*v=(a+ib)v$ where $a_{11},a_{10},...a_0 \in Z_p$ and $a,b \in R$?

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right site? Your question doesn't seem to be related to _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: I voted to close, perhaps cynically using the cheap "belongs on math.se.com" reason. But really this is a confused question since it is not stated what `p` is, and the mix of Zp with R looks to be either ill-defined, or garbage.